# AngularJS cascading drop-downs with partial filter values.

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Is it possible to have cascading drop-downs if the child drop-down only *partially* contains the string in the first drop-down?

```
EX: DROPDOWN1: TOOL1     DROPDOWN2: TAGFORTOOL1
               TOOL2                TAGFORTOOL2
               TOOL3                TAGFORTOOL3
```

When I select TOOL1, I want to see only TAGFORTOOL1, and so on.

Code (not working, second dropdown just doesn't filter):

```
<div ng-controller="ToolListController">
   <select ng-model="toolSelectionModel" ng-options="tool.id for tool in tools">
   </select>
</div> 

<div ng-controller="TagListController">   
   <select ng-model="tagSelectionModel" ng-options="tag.tagname for tag in tags 
       | filter:{tagname:toolSelectionModel.tool.id}">
   </select>
</div>
```

Controllers:

```
reportingControllers.controller('TagListController', ['$scope', 'TagsResource',     function($scope, TagsResource) {
    $scope.tags = TagsResource.query(); // returns TAGFORTOOL1, TAGFORTOOL2, TAGFORTOOL3
}]);

reportingControllers.controller('ToolListController', function($scope) {
    $scope.tools = [
      {'id': 'TOOL1'},
      {'id': 'TOOL2'},
      {'id': 'TOOL3'},
    ];
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your controllers have different scopes for one thing, so I don't think toolSelectionModel is even available to the filter. THat said I tried putting them both in the same scope and it still didn't work. I was able to get it to work using my own filter like this.

```
     $scope.filtertags = function(a,b) {
          if(a.tagname.indexOf($scope.toolSelectionModel.id) > 0) {
             return true; }
           else { return false; }
     };
```

and apply it like this

```
        <select ng-model="tagSelectionModel" ng-options="tag.tagname for tag in tags 
           | filter:filtertags">
```

and putting both selections into the same controller so they are in the same scope.

Here is the complete controller. Just have a SINGLE controller in a div around both of your selects rather than giving a different controller for each one.

```
 app.controller('TagListController', ['$scope',     
     function($scope) {

       $scope.toolSelectionModel; 
     $scope.tags = [
      {'tagname': 'TAGFORTOOL1'},
       {'tagname': 'TAGFORTOOL2'},
      {'tagname': 'TAGFORTOOL3'},
    ];

    $scope.tools = [
      {'id': 'TOOL1'},
      {'id': 'TOOL2'},
      {'id': 'TOOL3'},
    ];

    $scope.filtertags = function(a,b) {
      if(a.tagname.indexOf($scope.toolSelectionModel.id) > 0) {
         return true; }
        else { return false; }
      };
    }]);
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, obviously I'm new at this :). I tried your way and I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" on that first if statement line. 
So it doesn't know about toolSelectionModel at this point?

Comment: To do it this way you'll need to have just a single controller. Here is how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it! Two things:
First, both lists had to be in the same scope as Scott said - thanks!
Second, my TagListController did not know about the toolSelectionModel (I realized this when I tried printing out the selected value).

So the correct code is to bring everything under the one controller. Pretty simple and slick once you get past the newbie mistakes :)

```
<div ng-controller="TagListController">
   <select ng-model="toolSelectionModel" ng-options="tool.id for tool in tools">
   </select>

   <select ng-model="tagSelectionModel" ng-options="tag.tagname for tag in tags 
     | filter:toolSelectionModel.id">
   </select>
</div>
```